# jQuery messing with css

Tags: jquery, html

I have a shopping cart Icon in my nav bar with a number showing an increment if the user chooses to "add to cart".

Although, when loading the page the icon is fine, however when adding 1 item to the cart, it produces a duplicate of the cart and badge that holds the number items.

```
if ($totalquantity >= 0) {
    echo '<div class="badge"'.$totalquantity.'">
          <i class="cart-icon" ></i>
          </div>';
}
```

jquery

```
$('body').on('click', '.addCartButton', function(){
    var index = $(this).data('id');
    var quantity = $(this).siblings('input').val();
    $.ajax ({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'add_to_cart.php?index='+index,
        data: {
            orderQuantity: quantity
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.cart-icon').load('badge');          
        }
    })
});
```

add_to_cart.php

```
$index = $_GET['index'];

//from product.php
if(isset($_POST['orderQuantity'])){
    $orderQuantity = $_POST['orderQuantity'];

    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$index]))
        $_SESSION['cart'][$index] += $orderQuantity;
    else
        $_SESSION['cart'][$index] = $orderQuantity;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You probably want `$('.badge').html(data);` instead of `$('.cart-icon').load('badge');`

Comment: `$('.cart-icon').load` will load new content into `.cart-icon` which is the `<i>` icon - you want to replace this, not load content into it.  Inspect the HTML after you add items and it will be like `<div class='badge'><i class='cart-icon'><div class='badge'><i class='cart-icon'></i></div></i></div>` (and will likely add 2 if you add another)

Comment: makes the shopping cart icon disappear and the badge doesnt increment its value. but there is no duplicate

Comment: What does `add_to_cart.php` return?

Comment: just increments the value

Comment: when i inspect the one with the duplicate, one has ::before and the other ::after

Comment: "just increments the value" - so doesn't return anything?   What does `<div class="badge"'.$totalquantity.'">` actually output?  as it looks like it would `<div class="badge"123>` which isn't valid HTML.  Whatever the solution, you don't want `.load` http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Do you have `badge` as a php file?  What does that return?   Did you try:  `$('.badge').load('badge');` ?

Comment: i've added the add_to_cart.php

Comment: and no i dont have a badge.php